# Any way i can check if a url points to a valid image (using JS/PHP/ZendFramework)?

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework, validation

i am developing a test/learning app. i wonder how can i test if an image from another site/domain ... i broke up my validation logic to the following

- exists
- is an image
- is of valid type
- is of a specific dimensions
- is below a max size - say i want the image to load quickly. tho the hosting resource is not mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/getimagesize) can do all but the last of your points. For that you can use [`filesize()`](http://php.net/filesize). For `filesize()` you'll have to actually download it though, but seeing as `getimagesize()` also requires that, you can just save it to a temporary file. You can use [`tempnam()`](http://php.net/tempnam) to get a temporary file that doesn't conflict with others.

Answer (score 0):

1. checking if url exists:

   `$handle = curl_init($url);
   curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
   $response = curl_exec($handle);
   $status = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
   if($status == 404) {//return true or whatever}`
2. is an image, is of valid type:
   determine if the file extension is valid, for example using

   `preg_match('/(jp[e]?g|png|gif|etc...)$/i', $url);`
3. is of specific dimensions:
   use GD to create a resource and then check size by `getImageSize($resource)`
4. is below max size:
   in addition to step 1 - `$size = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD);`

Remember that you must have `cURL` and `GD` enabled.

Comment: so i see that i still need to download the file ... hmm